# Excel IF statement with AND/OR combination doesn't work

Tags: microsoft-excel

My Excel formula is able to identify everything up until this time wherein it uses the first computation rather than the 2nd one.

The formula I'm using:

`=IF(OR(A21="Ensure Plus",A21="Glucerna RTH",A21="Nepro Hp",A21="Novasource",A21="Supportan",AND(OR(B21>F11,AND(($E$19-E21)<=5,($E$19-E21)<=(-5)),AND(($F$19-F21)<=5,($F$19-F21)<=(-5))),AND(($G$19-G21)<=5,($G$19-G21)<=(-5)))),B21-50,IF(OR(AND(($E$19-E21)<=5,($E$19-E21)<=(-5)),AND(($F$19-F21)<=5,($F$19-F21)<=(-5)),AND(($G$19-G21)<=5,($G$19-G21)<=(-5))),B21-3,"Cannot Be"))`

Here's a screenshot of the worksheet:

[image: Worksheet]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? As it is written it is not clear what you are asking, where the problem is, what the desired behavior is, and why it is bad that it is using the 1st or 2nd computational formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troubleshooting tip for long and complex formulas:

Break down the formula into manageable parts in individual cells. Then you can identify which conditions resolve correctly and which don't.  Once all cells with parts of the formula display the correct result, start combining the formulas in two of the cells and check the result. Repeat until all formula parts have been combined in the main formula.

Without any indication what your business rules and logic are, this is the only answer that comes to mind.

Comment: thank you for the answer, I used the evaluate formula and found out where the error was coming from. My value for "or" was also considering the "and" statement, making the statement true and uses the first formula